# How do I diagnose and visualize high ping times to wifi router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm seeing erratic and sometimes very long ping times to my wifi router that's just one hop away. Pinging `192.168.1.1` sometimes gives stretches of 400-800ms latencies.

There are plenty of things to try (firmware, router placement, AP channel, etc.), but I would like to attack this problem a bit more methodically:

- First, how can I *visualize* the performance of my network?
- Then, how can I *benchmark* the performance of a given configuration, so that I can compare reliably after making adjustments?

Comment: What router and/or on-board router software are you using if it is not the stock install?

Comment: @JeffClayton Linksys WRT54GSv2 (old-school) running Tomato (Shibby). Used to run DD-WRT but it's been buggy and confusing to maintain.

Comment: Interesting yet familiar, I used to have a WRT54G as well, also running DD-WRT.

Comment: Do you have an actual problem or is this purely a cosmetic issue? WiFi routers are not generally designed to be super-fast ping responders, they have real work to do.

Comment: Tools commonly used to diagnose Wi-Fi issues can actually cause this problem. When scanning for Wi-Fi networks the radio has to go off channel, typically it tells the AP to buffer frames for it so it can 'sleep' then switches channels to scan.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz we should be able to complete a full roundtrip to a wifi AP in under 10ms, no? If your intra-wifi latency is above 500ms then EVERY PACKET you pull from the web/internet also suffers this latency. It's killer.

Comment: @PaulIrish All true, but that has nothing to do with ping times. Ping measures the sum of network latency plus the ping response latency itself. SoHo WiFi routers are not meant to be efficient ping responders, so using ping to measure network latency is not recommended.

Answer (score 80):

[This serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/649647/intermittently-high-ping-times-to-router-via-wi-fi) has good high-level guidance on what to do - so start with that. That last step is a real doozy though: presumably you (I mean, me) don't want to invest in dedicated hardware for this...

Below are some good tools, first for understanding connectivity health within the local wifi network, and then to an internet endpoint.

## Wifi Tools

### [NetSpot](http://www.netspotapp.com/) (for mac)

It tracks the local WiFI APs and provides basic data like SNR, Channel, Signal Strength. It can also do a basic site survey for a physical space indicating strengths and interference. In the AP discovery mode, you can also chart signal strength over time, allowing you to test placements and adjust interference possibilities.
[image] 
[image]
[image]

### [Wifi Speed Test for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pzolee.android.localwifispeedtester&hl=en)

Very helpful. You'll run a simple python server on your machine and the app can test a few scenarios giving you realtime speed feedback.

[image]

**[Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer)**, another great android app, has a few valuable views of what AP wifi channels are active. Might be the best free tool for choosing AP channel without doing a lot of work.

### [iPerf](http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php)

Well respected tool for understanding local network performance. You need two boxes, one as server, one as client. You can set up a number of parameters, run a test, and see the results for bandwidth and jitter. I perfer using it with the [jPerf GUI](http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php#jperf) for charting results and tweaking parameters.

```
brew install iperf
iperf -s # on server, next one on client
iperf -c 192.168.1.XXX -P 1 -i 1 -p 5001 -f m -t 60
```

[image]

## Internet Connectivity Health

### [mtr](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) (ping & traceroute combined)

Pings all your traceroute hops. Provides trend data. Crazy awesome.

```
brew install mtr
mtr 8.8.4.4
```

[image]

### [speedtest-cli](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli)

The CLI version of the common ookla speedtest.net thing. The project maintainer declares it's not consistent, but still, it's handy to try to gauge large differences.

```
wget -O speedtest-cli https://raw.github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest_cli.py
chmod +x speedtest-cli
speedtest-cli --list | head # and chose a top server (sorted by distance)
speedtest-cli --server 2761 # re-use the same server
```

### [NPAD](http://www.psc.edu/index.php/networking/644-npad-diagnostic-pathdiag) : Network Path and Application Diagnosis

Automatic diagnostic server for troubleshooting end-systems and last-mile network problems. After running a battery of tests, gives a [Result Summary page like this](http://ps.psc.xsede.org:8000/ServerData/Reports-2014-12/209.133.52.233.available.above.net:2014-12-05-02:09:46.html). I recommend using this [NPAD server redirect link](http://mlab-ns.appspot.com/npad?format=redirect) to find the closest NPAD server (they're all over) and using that hostname for your tests.

```
  wget http://netspeed.usc.edu:8000/diag-client.c
  cc diag-client.c -o diag-client
# ./diag-client <server_name> <port> <target_RTT> <target_data_rate_in_MB/S>
  ./diag-client ps.psc.xsede.org 8001 30 5
```

[image]

---

## My personal results:

I spent a good few hours doing all this, trying different things (switching from DD-WRT to Tomato firmware) and reading. Turns out it wasn't network layer and was good old RF interference, mostly from Bluetooth! I had my computer, a bluetooth mouse and keyboard within 5 feet of the router. (And old router still on 2.4Ghz where they clash.)

For this, I got the most out of *Wifi Speed Test for Android*, running that regularly while I moved things around in the apartment. Since it reports updates every 200ms or so, it clearly communicated when interference was dropping my packets.

I definitely recommend reading the [Common Sources of Interference](https://support.metageek.net/hc/en-us/articles/200628894-Common-Sources-of-Interference) guide from Metageek. (They also make InSSIDer and other Wifi analysis tools that seem good.)

[image]

One tool I didn't have was a physical spectrum analysis meter. Phones and laptops can only detect Wifi APs, but can't pick up on interference from Bluetooth or other RF-based technologies. Metageek has some nice solutions in this space ([Wi-Spy](http://www.metageek.net/products/wi-spy/) and [inSSIDer Office](http://www.inssider.com/)) and hopefully we see more tools emerge like [AirShark](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/wings/projects/airshark/).

Comment: These are beautiful tools, updating my notes.

Comment: Another "quick and dirty" tool which is invaluable because its portable is Wifi Analyser for Android devices.

Comment: Aye. I mentioned WiFi analyzer briefly; it might be the best tool for understanding AP channel interference, though in my case, that wasn't an issue. That said, it's really well done.

Comment: Great list, thanks. Another thing to always try is to see what happens *without* wifi. Once I had what I thought was a wifi problem, but plugging directly into the cable feeding the wifi AP and running iPerf revealed a Bad Cable as the real culprit!

Comment: Hmmmm. Bluetooth is very unlikely to cause the sort of interference you describe, it's usual AFS hopping pattern will avoid a typical 20MHz Wi-Fi signal in 2.4GHz. You weren't running 40Mhz channels were you?

Comment: Great guide Paul! I had the best luck with iPerf and also found an iPerf app for my Android phone, which I found worked well with the server app. That way I could see my gigabit ethernet connection get one rate via iPerf and my Android phone on the wifi get a different rate - to compare apples to apples. My fix was setting a Tomato router setting that tries to mitigate interference from other devices. Immediate speed boost after that.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in my comment above: Tools commonly used to diagnose Wi-Fi issues can actually cause this problem. When scanning for Wi-Fi networks the radio has to go off channel, typically it tells the AP to buffer frames for it so it can 'sleep' then switches channels to scan.

Additionally, iOS and OS X since AirDrop was introduced, will take the Wi-Fi radio off channel to look for other AirDrop services and since Yosemite will periodically go off channel to support handoff.

Comment: Great point - I've noticed this problem using InSSIDer in the past - nice to get an explanation for it.

Answer (score 3):

So I had these Wi-Fi ping fluctuations to the router too.

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=2.334 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.813 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=2749.664 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=1748.912 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=748.162 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=1.796 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=1.806 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=1.991 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=63 time=1.797 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=63 time=1.832 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=10 ttl=63 time=1.713 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=63 time=1.819 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=63 time=1.616 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=13 ttl=63 time=1.748 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=63 time=1.677 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=15 ttl=63 time=3427.213 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=63 time=2426.371 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=17 ttl=63 time=1425.634 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=18 ttl=63 time=424.834 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=63 time=1.829 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=20 ttl=63 time=1.691 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=21 ttl=63 time=2.038 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=22 ttl=63 time=1.679 ms
^C--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
23 packets transmitted, 23 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.616/564.346/3427.213/1015.102 ms
```

I switched the router (from TL-WR743ND to DIR-815), tried several Wi-Fi USB adapters (mostly TP-LINKs, though I think I had the issue with D-Link DWA-160 too), went from 2.5 GHz to 5GHz and scoured the channels. No luck, the problem persisted.

Till I noticed that when I do a network speed test or run a bittorrent client the ping is all right. It only fluctuates when the network is idle.

Might be a Windows 7 issue or a thing with my TP-LINK adapters, but when I give a bit of a load on the Wi-Fi the fluctuation vanishes and the network works all right.

So far I've made a little Rust program to keep my Wi-Fi network up.

```
// Need a constant wifi load in order not to have the ping drops.
fn wifi_load() {
  // This *might* be useful if the router suddenly supports Keep-Alive.
  // Not the case with DIR-815 though, we'll keep making new connections to it.
  let config = hyper::client::pool::Config {max_idle: 1};

  let client = hyper::client::Client::with_pool_config (config);
  loop {
    let url = "http://192.168.0.1/css/init.css";
    if let Err (err) = client.get (url) .send() {
      log! ("wifi_load] Error fetching {}: {}", url, err);
      sleep (Duration::from_secs (9));}
    sleep (Duration::from_millis (100));}}
```